# How can I get a string inside an if Statement?

Tags: c#

I have a problem, I am trying to make a Sound-Bord App in C#.
I tried to write an `If` Statement that recognizes if a key got pressed. I made an  `If` Statement like this:

```
if ((Keyboard.GetKeyStates(Key.(K)) & KeyStates.Down) > 0)
   {
   soundPlayer.Play();
   Presst = true;
   ja.Text = ("Works!");
   }
   else
   ....
```

I made it like it was told in this Video: [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1vvZs-lUc8).
It works fine, but i have to put a Strig instead of an Key on the Keybord

```
   if ((Keyboard.GetKeyStates(Key.(AString)) & KeyStates.Down) > 0)
```

So i need a way to put my Strig inside the `if` Statement. Can someone help me?

### Error Code:

1. Identifier expected,
2. `"Key"` does not get a definition for `""`.

It's my first Programm I've ever made... so I'm a noob in Progamming (Sorry :/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Enum.Parse`

```
if ((Keyboard.GetKeyStates((Key)Enum.Parse(typeof(Key), "K")) & KeyStates.Down) > 0)
```